# How to get list of terminated and running pods list using Kubectl command

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl

I want to see the list of terminated and running pods details in Kubernetes.

Below command only shows the running pods, somehow I want to see the history of all pods so far terminated.

```
$ ./kubectl get pods -o wide
NAME     READY     STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE       IP              NODE
POD1     1/1       Running   0          3d        10.333.33.333   node123
POD2     1/1       Running   0          4d        10.333.33.333   node121
POD3     1/1       Running   0          1m        10.333.33.333   node124
```

I expect the terminated pods list using kubectl command

Answer (score -1):

[Since v1.10](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/blob/master/CHANGELOG-1.10.md#deprecations) `kubectl` prints terminated pods by default:

> `--show-all` (which only affected pods and only for human
>   readable/non-API printers) is now defaulted to true and deprecated.
>   The flag determines whether pods in a terminal state are displayed. It
>   will be inert in 1.11 and removed in a future release.

If running older versions than v1.10, you still need to use the `--show-all` flag.

Comment: Exactly, let me see how can get history of PODs on particular node, may be using Prometheus ? I will post if I find solution.